# Как записать правильно вот такой селектор JavaScript [не jQuery]

Tags: javascript

Хотелось бы записать вот такой селектор:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".smallinnertable:not(:has(a))");
```

На jQuery работает, а на чистом JS нет. Такой селектор очень нужен. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan причем тут jquery? Он лишь упоминается, но вопрос не о нем

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский да просто подумал раз упоминается то надо и его

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan  Я что-то упустил? Переписка не полная.

Comment: @EugenEray, переписка полная, но начинается с [3й ревизии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/668401/revisions).

Comment: @Qwertiy  Понял. Спс.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вряд ли что-то есть прям в точности легкое и простое. Ведь даже на *Jquery* написан хорошенький и хитрый фильтр для селекторов.

Поэтому, как вариант, написать что-то самому. Например что-то подобное:

```js
function getElementHasNotAnother(selector, filterEl) {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll(selector),
    filter   = Array.prototype.filter;
    
    return filter.call( divs, function( node ) {     
        return node.querySelectorAll(filterEl).length == 0;
    });        
}

var result = getElementHasNotAnother('.smallinnertable', 'a');

/*********** check *************************/
for (var el in result) {
 console.log(result[el].textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="smallinnertable">1231</div>
<div class="smallinnertable">werjhwer</div>
<div class="smallinnertable">879879</div>
<div class="smallinnertable">4 <a href="">34</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> document.querySelectorAll(".smallinnertable:not(:has(a))");
> ```

Сначала надо выбрать `.smallinnertable`, а потом выкинуть из них все те, в которых есть `a`:

```js
console.log(
  Array.prototype.filter.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".smallinnertable"),
    function (el) { return !el.querySelector("a") }
  )
)
```

```html
<div class="smallinnertable">1231</div>
<div class="smallinnertable">werjhwer</div>
<div class="smallinnertable">879879</div>
<div class="smallinnertable">4 <a href="">34</a></div>
```

На css пока ничего подобного нет, так что только фильтровать.
Ну и осторожнее, если селектор внутри `has` составной.

Comment: Тоже хороший вариант.

Comment: Почти такой же - разница только в `querySelector` вместо `querySelectorAll` для проверки и предупреждении про составные селекторы.

Comment: Я бы показал, для чего я использую этот селектор, но я с телефона, и не могу сейчас.

Comment: Я всё равно не помню, как именно проверяет `has`. Но между `querySelectorAll` и jQuery'ным `find` есть очень существенная разница с составными селекторами. Есть вероятность на неё и тут нарваться.

Comment: Судя по всему в CSS  такой селектор фиг сделаешь.

Comment: @EugenEray, на css точно не сделаешь. Первый шаг в направлении выбора на основе содержимого - это [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) - больше пока ничего нет и не особо-то планируется, кажется.